# vb.net how to programatically read project > props > Publish > Publish Version > Revision

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I want to display the Revision # on the title of my VB.NET windows app form title.

I tried ver = Application.ProductVersion
but only get:  "1.0.6507.29738"

However, my project > props > Publish > Publish Version > 
is actually:
major = 1
minor = 2
build = 0
Revision = 7

Answer (score 0):

Get the revision first then put it in the title label

```
    If (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) Then
        With System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion
            lbl_title.Text = "Current Version: " & .Major & "." & .Minor & "." & .Build & "." & .Revision
        End With
    End If
```

**Noted That:** This revision will appear only when the application is published.